# Difficulty plotting 4 non-numeric variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, kable

I have data like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(Majors = c('Sam', 'Bob', 'Henry', 'John', 'Ted', 'Carl', 
                          'Robert', 'Matt', 'Jared', 'Jack', 'Greg', 
                          'Arthur', 'Glenn'), 
                 MEASURES = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 
                              'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'), 
                 LCOs = c(1.1, 2.1, 3.3, 4.1, 1.2, 1.1,
                          2.4, 3.3, 2.3, 1.1, 2.1, 1.4, 7), 
                 Years=c('2017-2018', '2017-2018', '2017-2018', 
                         '2018-2019', '2018-2019', '2018-2019',
                         '2018-2019', '2019-2020', '2020-2021', 
                         '2020-2021', '2020-2021', '2020-2021', 
                         '2021-2022'))
```

My goal is to plot (or table?) this so that `Majors` is x-axis/bottom, `Measures` is y-axis/side, `LCOs` is plotted accordingly, and `Years` is represented by coloring the plotted `LCOs` values. Based on my attempts so far, I'm thinking `ggplot2` options may not be best. But `kable` doesn't seem to want to "plot" (for lack of better term) them.

I'd very grateful for any help!

**EDIT TO INCLUDE PITIFUL SKETCH OF DESIRED OUTCOME**

[image]

Comment: ... and to be clear, just trying to help you get the help you need! Comments only have limited space so often have to convey information brusquely.

Comment: @jpsmith so can you suggest a package that's suitable to what I'm trying to do? Sorry I didn't post all my failed attempts in the OP, and sorry it may seem to some I'm trying to get others to do my work for me.

Comment: "Plotted accordingly" is pretty vague. Perhaps `ggplot(DF, aes(Majors, MEASURES, size = LCOs, color = Years)) + geom_point()`. If that's not it I recommend you draw a picture because your description isn't clear. Here's an intro to ggplot2: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html

Comment: @JonSpring, thank you for attempting to help! I know it's a poorly formed question, but I'm not sure how to articulate my aim. I have edited OP to include a a (pitiful!) sketch. I want the `LCOs` to appear under the appropriate `Majors` (column) and along the appropriate `Measures` and colored the appropriate `Years`. Again--very thankful if you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(DF |> mutate(Majors = factor(Majors) |> fct_inorder(),
                    MEASURES = factor(MEASURES) |> fct_rev()), 
       aes(Majors, MEASURES, label = LCOs, color = Years)) + 
  geom_text() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: please accept my heartfelt thanks! I think I can figure out the fine-tuning from here.